# Why do I get and how to remove duplicates from solr results regarding my unique field?

Tags: xml, solr

I am using Solr 3.6.0 for full-text search.
I have the following fields defined in my schema.xml:

```
<field name="productNumber" type="ngramtext" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />  
<field name="additionalTextData" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I have also the following field type defined:

```
<fieldType name="ngramtext" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="3" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

This creates a tokens with size 2 and 3 and places them in the index. Great for searching [SKUs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock-keeping_unit). For now they go in the same index, and I know that this might create performance issues. But I decided to deal with that when the performance issue appears. For the data set that I have now, the speed is great (subjectively speaking :))

I also have the following:

```
<uniqueKey>productNumber</uniqueKey>
```

In the solrconfig.xml I have placed the additionalTextData for every "df" part:

```
="df">="df">additionalTextData<
```

When I do the following query:

select?indent=on&version=2.2&q=productNumber:12&fq=&start=0&rows=10000&fl=productNumber,additionalTextData&wt=json&explainOther&hl.fl

or

select?indent=on&version=2.2&q=productNumber:12&fq=additionalTextData:*&start=0&rows=10000&fl=productNumber,additionalTextData&wt=json&explainOther&hl.fl

**I get 2345 results with some of them repeating. I search by some productNumber and I can see it twice or 3 times. Why does this happen? And how can I overcome this?**

**EDIT1:**
I found out also that adding:

```
<filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
```

in ngramtext fieldType after all other filters, doesn't solve the issue.

**SOLUTION1 according to mbonaci:**
instead of:

```
<field name="productNumber" type="ngramtext" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
```

place:

```
<field name="productNumber" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="productNumberCopyField" type="ngramtext" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
```

After the fields tag add:

```
<copyField source="productNumber" dest="productNumberCopyField" />
```

And, specify the following query:

select?indent=on&version=2.2&q=**productNumberCopyField**:12&fq=additionalTextData:*&start=0&rows=10000&fl=productNumber,additionalTextData&wt=json&explainOther&hl.fl

Comment: Unique key should not be ngram. Use a separate field that you wont index. Or simpler (I don't know why would you tokenize product number), just make `productNumber` of type `int` or `string`.

Comment: OK, I see, `SKUs`, but then leave `productNumber` as it is and add additional field `productID` which you wont analyze and use it as `uniqueKey`.

Comment: The productNumber is mixed characters (letters, numbers and special chars). And I need solr to return queries on any 2 or 3 consecutive characters for the productNumber.  This is why its an ngram. What does the ngram type have to do with the uniqueness of the field? As much as I understand, the index analyzer is going to create ngrams for each productNumber. The query analyzer should check if that ngram exists in the index and return the appropriate full productNumber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the index analyzer is going to create ngrams, but then Solr is going to use that ngrams to form unique key. Does that make sense to you? Multivalue unique keys?

E.g. if you have product key `tis876a` you'll end up with `ti is s8 87 76 6a tis is8 s87 876 76a` as your end result. That's all your unique key.

So simply use copy-field of type `lowercase` (it's not tokenized, just lowercased) and use `tis876a` as your product key (if it's in fact unique field in your data model, of course).

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem. If someone wants to see the specific implementation, look for it at the end of the question. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for reporting back with solution example. I'm glad my suggestion was helpful.